# what is use of adding length property to objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Array do support length property as well as string does, but objects don't inherently have a length property.

in case we add a length properly as below.

```
{"a":0,"b":0,length:2}
```

what is the use case scenario for above code

Comment: thanks for pointing out

Comment: One scenario would be to avoid to use `Object.keys (<your_object>).length` every time you need to know how many keys it inherit.

Comment: `what is use of adding length property to objects in javascript?`  Oh, this is so you can have a property called length on the object..  It might represent the length of your left leg, the length of a piece of string.  There might be more, but can't think of any atm.

Comment: @wayneOS I think that's the only reason, it uses fewer resources if it's stored but you have to remember to edit it each time you add or remove something.

Comment: @AndrewBone You nailed it. It uses less computer resources, but more human resources. That makes it a terrible idea except in some very specific applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object doesn't have a `length`, per se. It depends on what this length represents.

For example, in the code you posted, it's not immediately obvious why the length is 4, but it might make sense in the context of what that object actually represents.

Comment: changed length to 2, doesn't adding length make object as an array like data structure

Comment: I like @keith's example of the `leg` object. So, really, it depends on what you want to do. Why you would want to use an object as an array-like structure when you have arrays is not very clear to me.

Comment: No it doesn't make the object like array. The two structures are different and used differently. If you want array structure then use an array. You can loop through the object properties without a need for a length, if that's what you you're trying to do. Other than that, I don't see why you want it to be like an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here are both methods of getting the length.

You'll notice if you keep track of your own length the display code is a bit shorter but you need a whole function to add a new key, you'd even need another function to remove them.

`object.keys` changes the keys into an array which we can get the length from this, of course, take a few milliseconds more as it has to do the convert.

I generally run with the assumption a computer is going to make fewer mistakes than me so, if I can, I should load as much work as possible onto it.

```js
// initial set up
let obj1 = {"a":0,"b":0};
let obj2 = {"a":0,"b":0,length:2};

// initial lengths
console.log("obj1: "+Object.keys(obj1).length);
console.log("obj2: "+obj2.length);

// adding standard way
obj1["c"] = 0;

// adding to accomidate with length
function addObj2(key, value) {
  obj2[key] = value;
  obj2.length++;
}
addObj2("c",0);

console.log("--");

// new lengths
console.log("obj1: "+Object.keys(obj1).length);
console.log("obj2: "+obj2.length);
```

I hope this makes sense.